# Low throughput while using http remoting C#

Tags: c#, performance, proxy, remoting

I am using http remoting in C# to talk between two applications.
Earlier when I was running both applications on a single machine/two machines, it was very slow. 
We have a proxy server to connect to the internet. We set "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" in IE and now when I run both applications on one machine the communication is happening quite fast. (by a factor of 10 nearly)

But if I run each application on a different machine then it is still slow, like it was the case before setting the "Bypass proxy server..."

Any insight will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of data are you sending, and at what rate? And are you using lots of calls to remote (`MarshalByRefObject`) objects?

In reality, it is hard to fully control the data with remoting. Personally, I would recommend something message-based, for example WCF. This makes the interfaces between systems much more explicit and predictable.

If the proxy is being a pinch-point, you can still bypass this for remote addresses via proxycfg.exe

Answer (score 0):

There aren't a lot of remote calls, as feared.
A single remote call takes 10 secs on different machines while it takes only 350ms when on a single machine.

when I run proxycfg.exe, it shows "Direct Access (no proxy server)"